# How to stop animation in the current state in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello i wrote a simple code where i created an animation with a Circle which changes its position. I want the animation to stop when i tap on that Circle, but it doesn't stop, no matter that i set the animation to nil. Maybe my approach is wrong in some way. I will be happy if someone helps.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var enabled = true
    @State private var offset  = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .offset(y: CGFloat(self.offset))
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(self.enabled ? .easeIn(duration: 5) : nil) {
                    self.offset = Double(-UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height + 300)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                self.enabled = false
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Schottky stated above, the `offset` value has already been set, `SwiftUI` is just animating the changes.

The problem is that when you tap the circle, `onAppear` is not called again which means `enabled` is not checked at all and even if it was it wouldn’t stop the `offset` from animating.

To solve this, we can introduce a `Timer` and do some small calculations, `iOS` comes with a built-in `Timer` class that lets us run code on a regular basis. So the code would look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset  = 0.0
    // 1
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var animationDuration: Double = 5.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .offset(y: CGFloat(self.offset))
            .onTapGesture {
                // 2
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                // 3
                animationDuration -= 0.1
                if animationDuration <= 0.0 {
                    timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                } else {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                        self.offset += Double(-UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height + 300)/50
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

1. This creates a timer publisher which asks the timer to fire every `0.1` seconds. It says the timer should run on the `main` thread, It should run on the `common` run loop, which is the one you’ll want to use most of the time. (Run loops lets `iOS` handle running code while the user is actively doing something, such as scrolling in a list or tapping a button.)
2. When you tap the circle, the timer is automatically cancelled.
3. We need to catch the announcements (publications) by hand using a new modifier called `onReceive()`. This accepts a publisher as its first parameter (in this came it's our timer) and a function to run as its second, and it will make sure that function is called whenever the publisher sends its change notification (in this case, every 0.1 seconds).

After every 0.1 seconds, we reduce the duration of our animation, when the duration is over (duration = 0.0), we stop the timer otherwise we keep decreasing the `offset`.

Check out [triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer) to learn more about `Timer`

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation and for the great answer!

Answer (score 2):

After going through many things, I found out something that works for me. At the least for the time being and till I have time to figure out a better way.

```
struct WiggleAnimation<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content
    @Binding var animate: Bool
    @State private var wave = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            if animate {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                    .offset(x: -25, y: -25)
            }
        }
        .id(animate) //THIS IS THE MAGIC
        .onChange(of: animate) { newValue in
            if newValue {
                let baseAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)
                withAnimation(baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    wave.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(animate ? (wave ? 2.5 : -2.5) : 0.0),
                        anchor: .center)
    }

    init(animate: Binding<Bool>,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self._animate = animate
    }
}
```

Use

```
@State private var editMode = false

WiggleAnimation(animate: $editMode) {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: image)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.1,
                   height: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.1)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(.gray)
        
        Text(text)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .font(KMFont.tiny)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

What do you have to change?
make an offset as @Binding, provide from outside

How does it work?
.id(animate) modifier here does not refresh the view but just replaces it with a new one, and since you have offset as binding property, replaced view will have the correct offset.

Again this might not be the best solution but it works for my case.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand is that only something that has already happened is being animated. It just takes longer to show. So in other words, when you set your offset to some value, it is going to animate towards that value, no matter what. What you, therefore, need to do is to set the offset to zero when tapping on the circle. The animation system is smart enough to deal with the 'conflicting' animations and cancel the previous one.

Also, a quick tip: You can do `var offset: CGFloat = 0.0` so you don't have to cast it in the onAppear modifier

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but as i said i would like to stop the animation in the current state. In my case i am trying to make the animation stop and keep the circle position, which is on the moment of the tap

Comment: Oh I See. In this case, you should probably not look at SwiftUI since that‘s generally designed for apps like calendar or mail, e.t.c. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/ maybe that may help you